# Error when calling Rscript from command/matlab in windows

Tags: r, matlab

I have a script written in R and tested that it works out fine. The codes are the following:

```
setwd("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx")
rawdata <- read.delim("xxx.txt", check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(edgeR)
y <- DGEList(counts = rawdata[,7:14], genes = rawdata[,1:6])
o <- order(rowSums(y$counts),decreasing=TRUE)
y <- y[o,]
d <- duplicated(y$genes)
y <- y[!d,]
y$samples$lib.size <-colSums(y$counts)
rownames(y$counts) <- rownames(y$genes)
y$genes <-NULL
y <- calcNormFactors(y)
write.table(y$samples, file = "TMM_normalization_factors.txt")
```

This works out well when just running it in the R. However, when calling from either command line (windows cmd) or matlab, it shows the following error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : could not find function "getGeneric" 
Calls: order -> rowSums -> is.data.frame 
Execution halted
```

I am a new programmer and have very limited knowledge in programming. Could someone please tell me what is possibly wrong with this code? Thanks a lot.

Updated:
Just tested, the error is on the

```
rowSums
```

command. Rscript seems doesn't recognize this command? Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Can you indicate how you are calling it from the command line? I wouldn't expect that you could call an R script from Matlab.

Comment: For cmd, "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\TMM_script.R" will work. For matlab, system('"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\TMM_script.R"') could work. at least these 2 works for a simple hello_world

Comment: What type of object is returned by `DGEList`? `rowSums` works on matrices and data frames. Given the error, it looks like there's a problem checking whether the input to `rowSums` is a data frame ([docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html)).

Comment: You need to add `library(methods)` at the top of your script. Although a default package, it is not loaded by `Rscript`, go figure why... (maybe to save start-up time)

Answer (score 0):

As flodel mentioned in the comments above, the reason the code works when run directly from R and not when run with Rscript is because Rscript used to not load the methods package. Thus the solution is to load the methods package at the top of the script:

```
load(methods)
```

However, as of R 3.5.0 (released on 2018-04-23), the methods package is now loaded by default. From [R NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.3.html):

> If --default-packages is not used, then Rscript now checks the environment variable R_SCRIPT_DEFAULT_PACKAGES. If this is set, then it takes precedence over R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES. If default packages are not specified on the command line or by one of these environment variables, then Rscript now uses the same default packages as R. For now, the previous behavior of not including methods can be restored by setting the environment variable R_SCRIPT_LEGACY to yes.